# Comparing numbers in EL expression does not seem to work

Tags: jsp, if-statement, jstl, el

In JSP, I want to compare two variables

If I do:

```
<c:set var="pagerTotDisp" value="9"/>
<c:if test="${pagerTotDisp > 8}">
  <span>pagerTotDisp above 8</span>
</c:if>
```

It displays "pagerTotDisp above 8" as expected

```
<c:set var="TotalPages" value="10"/>
<c:if test="${TotalPages > 2}">
  <span>TotalPages above 2</span>
</c:if>
```

It displays "pagerTotDisp above 8" as expected

But then if I do

```
<c:set var="pagerTotDisp" value="9"/>
<c:set var="TotalPages" value="10"/>
<c:if test="${TotalPages < pagerTotDisp}">
  <span>This condition is not true. This text should not be displayed</span>
</c:if>
```

It displays "This condition is not true. This text should not be displayed".

What's going on?
Is that JSP not being able to handle two variables in a same condition??

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're hardcoding the value in the `value` attribute of `<c:set>`. The `<c:set>` treats the hardcoded values as `String`. EL is therefore also evaluating them as `String`. Lexicographically, `9` is greater than `10`, because `9` is at a further numerical position than `1`.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Set the value via an EL expression. It will be interpreted as `Long` instead of `String`.

   ```
   <c:set var="pagerTotDisp" value="${9}" />
   <c:set var="TotalPages" value="${10}" />
   ```
2. Or, use [`<fmt:parseNumber>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/parseNumber.html), which would be the only solution if you have those as `String` variables from elsewhere which you have no control over.

   ```
   <fmt:parseNumber var="pagerTotDisp" value="9" />
   <fmt:parseNumber var="TotalPages" value="10" />
   ```

Comment: thanks! it worked. You might want to add that the fmt taglib needs to be added:
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

Answer (score 5):

It treats both values as Strings, and compares them lexicographically.

Try

```
<c:set var="pagerTotDisp" value="${9}"/>
<c:set var="TotalPages" value="${10}"/>
<c:if test="${TotalPages < pagerTotDisp}">
  <span>This condition is not true. This text should not be displayed</span>
</c:if>
```